# Rewrite rule behaving differently on new server

Tags: mod-rewrite

I am on a shared host and my account was recently migrated to a new server. Unfortunately, this means I do not have the specifics on what configuration changes were made at the root level. However, a major change has occurred in how our mod_rewrite rule is being handled.

```
Options +ExecCGI +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

ModPagespeed off

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^static - [L,E=no-gzip:1]
RewriteRule ^sixteencolors-app/script/dispatch\.fcgi/.*$ - [L,E=no-gzip:1]
RewriteRule ^v0/(.*)$ sixteencolors-app/script/dispatch.fcgi/$1 [PT,L]
```

The intended result is that a request to `/v0/year/` should be rewritten to `/sixteencolors-app/script/dispatch.fcgi/year`, instead it is going to `/sixteencolors-app/script/dispatch.fcgi/v0/year/`

It worked before the migration, and no changes have been made on our end since then.

Comment: Try adding `Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews` before the rule-set.

Comment: Sorry, I did not paste the full .htaccess. I edited the original question to include the full file.